# Insurance Question Skipping Issue - Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a sort of quiz game using C# in Unity where the questions have to come in a certain order after pressing a button. My issue is that questions are being skipped, and instead of questions going in order 1, 2, 3, 4; they're instead going like 1, 4 thereby skipping questions 2 and 3 entirely.

I'm not at all familiar with C# or Unity, and even with coding, I'd say I have an intermediate understanding with it. So I'm not exactly understanding what the issue is. I've tried googling it but I haven't seen anything that related to my issue.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ClickingButtons : MonoBehaviour
{
public Button LeftButton;

public Button RightButton;

public Text LeftText;

public Text RightText;

public Text PlaceholderText;

int i = 0;

public void Start()
{

    LeftText.text = "Male";

    RightText.text = "Female";

    PlaceholderText.text = "Are you a male or a female?";


 }
public void SetTextLeft(string text)
{
    if (i == 0 )
    {
        i++;

        LeftText.text = "Yes";

        PlaceholderText.text = "Are you married?";

        RightText.text = "No";
    }
    if (i == 1){

        i++;

        PlaceholderText.text = "Do you have any kids?";
    }
}
public void SetTextRight(string text)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        i++;

        LeftText.text = "Yes";

        PlaceholderText.text = "Are you married?";

        RightText.text = "No";
    }
    if (i == 1){

        i++;

        PlaceholderText.text = "Do you have any kids?";
    }
}
```

}

This is where I believe where the problem lies:

```
public void Start()
    {

    LeftText.text = "Male";

    RightText.text = "Female";

    PlaceholderText.text = "Are you a male or a female?";


 }
public void SetTextLeft(string text)
{
    if (i == 0 )
    {
        i++;

        LeftText.text = "Yes";

        PlaceholderText.text = "Are you married?";

        RightText.text = "No";
    }
    if (i == 1){

        i++;

        PlaceholderText.text = "Do you have any kids?";
    }
}
public void SetTextRight(string text)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        i++;

        LeftText.text = "Yes";

        PlaceholderText.text = "Are you married?";

        RightText.text = "No";
    }
    if (i == 1){

        i++;

        PlaceholderText.text = "Do you have any kids?";
    }
}
```

I'm sure the issue is an easy one to fix, but I'm just not understanding it.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding it, but I think we need more code. How are the questions coded, and how are they called? From what you've posted, `Start()` does nothing besides setting some texts. Do you have any variations of `Update()`?

Comment: Think about what happens if you go into the first `if`. What will `i` become? Now, keep debugging. Why do you think you now enter the **second** `if`? _That is the heart of your problem I suspect. I also suspect you meant to use `else if` rather than `if`._

Comment: I have a strong feeling the user will have another method named SetTextRight(string text) which is also auto increment the 'i' variable, two methods performing an auto increment on the 'i' variable will cause this issue.

Comment: I've added in the rest of my code for those who requested it.

Comment: Off-topic: you are using a object oriented language, but you are programming pretty procedural. You could create a `Question` class with `QuestionText`, `Answer1` and `Answer2` properties. Then you store them all in a collection (a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) for example) and iterate through that list while asking the user those questions. It will be easier to add more questions later on that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a logical problem to me.

```
public void SetTextLeft(string text)
{
    if (i == 0 )
    {
        i++;
    }
    if (i == 1)
    {

        i++;
    }
}
```

I removed the question-specific code to call out the issue, but you check if `i == 0` and then increment within that `if` statement. Then you do another `if` statement checking if `i == 1`. You can kind of see that the logical problem in that.

Here's the pseudo-logic

```
i = 0
if i == 0
    i = 1
if i == 1
    i = 2
etc...
```

So the logic will continue incrementing `i` until there are no more if statements.

What you likely want is a `switch-case` statement or `if-else` statements. Here's two examples:

```
switch(i)
{
    case 0:
        i++;
        // show question 0
        break;
    case 1:
        i++;
        // show question 1
        break;
    case 2:
        i++;
        // show question 2
        break;
}
```

or you can use an `if-else` like this

```
if (i == 0)
{
    i++;
    // show question 0;
}
else if (i == 1)
{
    i++;
    // show question 1;
}
else if (i == 2)
{
    i++;
    // show question 2;
}
```

Comment: Huh, I've never even heard about switch-case until now, but it works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the `i++` is causing all your `if` conditions to be considered true.
Use an `else if` or better a `switch` statement.

I would also rename i to something indicating its purpose, e.g. _questionNumber.

---

### Switch-case

```
public void SetTextLeft(string text)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            LeftText.text = "Yes";
            PlaceholderText.text = "Are you married?";
            RightText.text = "No";
            break;
        case 1:
            PlaceholderText.text = "Do you have any kids?";
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("unexpected question number");
    }
}
```

### If-else

```
public void SetTextLeft(string text)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        i++;
        LeftText.text = "Yes";
        PlaceholderText.text = "Are you married?";
        RightText.text = "No";
    }
    else if (i == 1)
    {
        i++;
        PlaceholderText.text = "Do you have any kids?";
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Dan - just a note - you've got two `SetTextLeft` functions there :)